# filetransfer.download + reader.readAsText on PhoneGap(Cordova)2.0 iOS never works

Tags: cordova

filetransfer.download seems working fine, but reader.readAsText never works for a downloaded HTML file for instance. My environment is Cordova2.0 iOS.

1. filetransfer.download works fine for any remote files.
   I can see that using i-funbox file browser with my iOS device.
2. reader.readAsText works fine for the other existing files.
3. however, reader.readAsText never works for downloaded files by filetransfer.download API.

How come does this happen?? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle for a while, I use jQuery.load() + $(selector).html() function for remote html/text files extensively, instead of filetransfer.download + reader.readAsText, where it works fine.